# Class templated member function and return type inference

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I wanted to use the C++11 auto little specifier to deduce my return type , but the example in which i am trying to use it is a little different than its typical use.

I have a base class , and subclasses that derive certain member functions.

```
enum class state {composite1, composite2, composite3};
class material
{
public:

}
class sub_material1 : material
{
public:
 template<typename T>
 T* transform(state to_state)
 {
 T* material;
   switch(to_state){
      case(state::composite1) :
         //do transform computations
         // set material to return
         material = some_transformed_material;
         break;
      case(state::composite2):
         // do transform computation
         // set material to return
         material = some_transformed_material;
         break;
.
.
.
.
}
return material;
}
}
```

so if i had something like

```
sub_material1 mat1;
sub_material2 mat2;

mat2 = mat1.transform(state::composite2);
```

how can i use auto and decltype in this case given the fact that i have condition to test that can be very lengthy....decltype seems an overkill ?

How can the type be inferred ?

Thank you

Comment: can you create full example? what is some_transformed_material?

Answer (score 1):

This code will not work. Compiler can't deduce template argument based on return type, so you should set in manually:

```
auto mat2 = mat1.transform<sub_material2>(state::composite2);
```

if mat2 was declared before:

```
sub_material2 *mat2;
mat2 = mat1.transform<sub_material2>(state::composite2);
```

You are trying to mix pointer and non pointer type.

I suggest you to try the following:

```
struct composite1 {};
struct composite2 {};
struct composite3 {};

class material
{
public:

}

class sub_material1 : material
{
public:
sub_material1 transform(composite1)
{
        //do transform computations
        // set material to return
        return some_transformed_material;
}

sub_material2 transform(composite2)
{
        //do transform computations
        // set material to return
        return some_transformed_material;
}
.
.
.
.
}
```

then you can something like this:

```
sub_material1 mat1;
auto mat2 = mat1.transform(composite2{});
```

or

```
sub_material1 mat1;
sub_material2 mat2;

mat2 = mat1.transform(composite2{});
```

You can return pointer if you like, but then mat2 should by of type sub_material2*.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is also the following:

```
sub_material3 ma3 ;
mat3 = mat1.transform(state::composite3)
```

then the answer is: you can't. The compiler has to know at compile time which version of transform to call. You can do something like this:

```
template <enum class state>
struct state_material
{
    typedef type sub_material1 ;
} ;
```

and then specialize

```
template <>
struct state_material<state::composite1>
{
    typedef type sub_material1 ;
} ;

template <>
struct state_material<state::composite2>
{
    typedef type sub_material2 ;
} ;

template <>
struct state_material<state::composite3>
{
    typedef type sub_material3 ;
} ;
```

Then call like this:

```
mat2 = mat1.template transform<state_material<state::composite2>::type>()
```

Comment: I don't think you need the `template` disambiguation for the call, but I may be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The code in its current form won't work at all, and neither `auto` nor `decltype` are going to help much here. The compiler can't infere what the actual type of T is. So you would have to specify what that type is when calling `transform`:

```
mat2 = mat1.transform<sub_material2>(state::composite2);
```

However, there is still a problem: `transform` returns a `T*`, not a `T`, i.e. the assignment won't work unless you declared `mat2`to be of type `sub_material2*`.

If the method could return different types of materials based on a runtime parameter, you would have to e.g. return a pointer to an object of the base class `material`. Templates are for making *compile-time* decisions, but your method looks like it makes a *runtime* decision!